# from decimal to binary in c

Tags: c, loops, type-conversion

here is the function of converting decimal to binary

```
char *binbin(int n){
    static char bin[9];
    int x;

    for(x=0; x<8; x++){
      bin[x] = n& 0x80 ? '1':'0';
      n <<= 1;
}
    bin[x] = '\0';
    return bin;
}
```

In the loop, the input has AND operation with 128 to determine the digit either 1 or zero from position 0 to 7 for converting 8-bit binary code. My question is that why shift the **argument(n)** to left for two positions?

For example, if i call this function in main and set the argument as 4.

We know the **4** in 8-bit binary is **00000100**

**0x80** is **10000000**. Can someone write few examples to explain how does this loop convert the int to binary?

Comment: Run it in a debugger, step thru the code line by line and examine the values after each line. That's the way to understand code.

Comment: It's not shifting 2 positions, it's just shifting 1 position.

Comment: i am new to C..anyway i try learning debugger later in codeblock

Comment: Rather, you are converting _from_ binary/raw data to a sequence of ASCII ones and zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

Given the input `4`, the first time through the loop it will `AND` the following two numbers:

```
0x80 = 10000000
n    = 00000100
```

When these are anded, the result is `0`, so it puts `'0'` into the first element of `bin`.

Then it shifts `n` left 1 bit, so it `AND`s these numbers:

```
0x80 = 10000000
n    = 00001000
```

This is again `0`, so it puts `'0'` into the next element of `bin`.

This keeps repeating, and after 4 more shifts it will be:

```
0x80 = 10000000
n    = 10000000
```

This time the result of `AND` is not zero, so it puts `'1'` into that element of `bin`.

This repeats 2 more times, again getting `0` as the result of the `AND`, so it adds more `'0'` characters to `bin`.

Comment: thanks, understand it right now, the code get the value before 1 first of No.4 in binary until it reaches to 1 in binary of 128, then fill out the whole size of array with zeros, if there is not any AND operation to obtain 1 in binary conversion.